Create an AreaTarget with Vuforia on Unity at runtime without the .XML file
I have an Unity app that create AreaTarget at runtime using the "CreateAreaTarget" function using the .XML and .DAT file of the AreaTarget (https://developer.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverFactory.html#a618b8a8a914b5c82a653f69e02b583ce)
In one of the latest update, we no longer have to use the .XML file. Quote from the changelog :

Model Targets and Area Targets can now be loaded directly from the database.dat file without the presence of the dataset.xml. The vuEngineGetDatabaseTargetInfo() now supports target info extraction from the database.dat file without the presence of the dataset.xml.

So that's great, but the documentation doesn't specify what function to use when you only have the .DAT file. I'm guessing "vuEngineGetDatabaseTargetInfo" can extract the target name of the database from the .DAT file, but I can't find much information on it.
Thanks !
